# Listview Automatic Scrolling using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to implement automatic scrolling of a Listview using MVVM. I know that you can update the listview by calling ScrollIntoView but that requires Code Behind which I'm trying to avoid.

I've bound my ListView's ItemSource to an ObservableCollection and would like the Listview to automatically scroll down to the newest item added to the log.

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Log}" 
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedLine}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel>

                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>


        </ListView>
```

Comment: As alternative approach, you can add new items to the start of the collection using 'Insert' instead of 'Add'. Sometimes this is useful, especialy in case of logs (Windows Event Viewer as example) as new events are shown on top.
That`s not exactly an answer to your question, but if this approach is justified in your case, you won`t have to do automatic scrolling at all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Code-Behind in MVVM if it's view-specific. For example, I often use code-behind to set focus, run animations, alter the position of controls, etc. Since this code is view-related, it should run behind the view, not in the View Model with business logic.

Answer (score 2):

`MVVM` and `Attached Behaviors` go hand in hand. You can use attached behavior to scroll to new item after the `ObservableCollection.Add()` takes place...

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) is a good example that tries to bring a tree view item into scroll view while sticking to MVVM.